# PriorityClass doesn't populate its value to podSpec

Tags: kubernetes

env: vagrant + virtualbox

- kubernetes: 1.14
- docker 18.06.3~ce~3-0~debian
- os: debian stretch

I have priority classes:

```
root@k8s-master:/# kubectl get priorityclass
NAME                      VALUE        GLOBAL-DEFAULT   AGE
cluster-health-priority   1000000000   false            33m < -- created by me
default-priority          100          true             33m < -- created by me
system-cluster-critical   2000000000   false            33m < -- system
system-node-critical      2000001000   false            33m < -- system
```

default-priority - has been set as `globalDefault`

```
root@k8s-master:/# kubectl get priorityclass default-priority -o yaml

    apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1
    description: Used for all Pods without priorityClassName
    globalDefault: true <------------------
    kind: PriorityClass
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
          {"apiVersion":"scheduling.k8s.io/v1","description":"Used for all Pods without priorityClassName","globalDefault":true,"kind":"PriorityClass","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile"},"name":"default-priority"},"value":100}
      creationTimestamp: "2019-07-15T16:48:23Z"
      generation: 1
      labels:
        addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
      name: default-priority
      resourceVersion: "304"
      selfLink: /apis/scheduling.k8s.io/v1/priorityclasses/default-priority
      uid: 5bea6f73-a720-11e9-8343-0800278dc04d
    value: 100
```

I have some pods, which were created after policy classes creation

This

```
kube-state-metrics-874ccb958-b5spd         1/1     Running   0          9m18s   10.20.59.67   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
```

And this

```
tmp-shell-one-59fb949cb5-b8khc   1/1     Running   1          47s     10.20.59.73   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
```

kube-state-metrics pod is using priorityClass `cluster-health-priority`

```
root@k8s-master:/etc/kubernetes/addons# kubectl -n kube-system get pod kube-state-metrics-874ccb958-b5spd -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-07-15T16:48:24Z"
  generateName: kube-state-metrics-874ccb958-
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-state-metrics
    pod-template-hash: 874ccb958
  name: kube-state-metrics-874ccb958-b5spd
  namespace: kube-system
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: kube-state-metrics-874ccb958
    uid: 5c64bf85-a720-11e9-8343-0800278dc04d
  resourceVersion: "548"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-state-metrics-874ccb958-b5spd
  uid: 5c88143e-a720-11e9-8343-0800278dc04d
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kube-role
            operator: In
            values:
            - master
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube-state-metrics:v1.6.0
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: kube-state-metrics
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      name: http-metrics
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-state-metrics-token-jvz5b
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: k8s-master
  nodeSelector:
    namespaces/default: "true"
  priorityClassName: cluster-health-priority <------------------------
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: kube-state-metrics
  serviceAccountName: kube-state-metrics
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: dedicated
    operator: Equal
    value: master
  - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
    operator: Exists
  volumes:
  - name: kube-state-metrics-token-jvz5b
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: kube-state-metrics-token-jvz5b
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-07-15T16:48:24Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-07-15T16:48:58Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-07-15T16:48:58Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-07-15T16:48:24Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://a736dce98492b7d746079728b683a2c62f6adb1068075ccc521c5e57ba1e02d1
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube-state-metrics:v1.6.0
    imageID: docker-pullable://gcr.io/google_containers/kube-state-metrics@sha256:c98991f50115fe6188d7b4213690628f0149cf160ac47daf9f21366d7cc62740
    lastState: {}
    name: kube-state-metrics
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2019-07-15T16:48:46Z"
  hostIP: 10.0.2.15
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.20.59.67
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: "2019-07-15T16:48:24Z"
```

`tmp-shell` pod has nothing about priority classes at all:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-07-15T16:56:49Z"
  generateName: tmp-shell-one-59fb949cb5-
  labels:
    pod-template-hash: 59fb949cb5
    run: tmp-shell-one
  name: tmp-shell-one-59fb949cb5-b8khc
  namespace: monitoring
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: tmp-shell-one-59fb949cb5
    uid: 89c3caa3-a721-11e9-8343-0800278dc04d
  resourceVersion: "1350"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/monitoring/pods/tmp-shell-one-59fb949cb5-b8khc
  uid: 89c71bad-a721-11e9-8343-0800278dc04d
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - /bin/bash
    image: nicolaka/netshoot
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: tmp-shell-one
    resources: {}
    stdin: true
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-g9lnc
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: k8s-master
  nodeSelector:
    namespaces/default: "true"
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-g9lnc
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-g9lnc
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-07-15T16:56:49Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-07-15T16:57:20Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-07-15T16:57:20Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-07-15T16:56:49Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://545d4d029b440ebb694386abb09e0377164c87d1170ac79704f39d3167748bf5
    image: nicolaka/netshoot:latest
    imageID: docker-pullable://nicolaka/netshoot@sha256:b3e662a8730ee51c6b877b6043c5b2fa61862e15d535e9f90cf667267407753f
    lastState:
      terminated:
        containerID: docker://dfdfd0d991151e94411029f2d5a1a81d67b5b55d43dcda017aec28320bafc7d3
        exitCode: 130
        finishedAt: "2019-07-15T16:57:17Z"
        reason: Error
        startedAt: "2019-07-15T16:57:03Z"
    name: tmp-shell-one
    ready: true
    restartCount: 1
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2019-07-15T16:57:19Z"
  hostIP: 10.0.2.15
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.20.59.73
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: "2019-07-15T16:56:49Z"
```

According to the docs:

> The globalDefault field indicates that the value of this PriorityClass
>   should be used for Pods without a priorityClassName

and

> Pod priority is specified by setting the priorityClassName field of
>   podSpec. The integer value of priority is then resolved and populated
>   to the priority field of podSpec

So, the questions are:

1. Why `tmp-shell` pod is not using priorityClass `default-priority`, even it created after priority class with globalDefault to `true`?
2. Why `kube-state-metrics` pod does not have field `priority` with parsed value from the priority class `cluster-health-priority` in podSpec?(look at .yaml above)
3. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can reproduce it is by disabling the `Priority` Admission Controller by adding this argument `--disable-admission-plugins=Priority` to the `kube-api-server` definition which is under `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` of the Host running the API Server.

According to the [documentation](https://v1-14.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#which-plugins-are-enabled-by-default) in v1.14 this is enabled by default. Please make sure that it is enabled in your cluster as well.

Comment: omg, that really was the case! I'm working on upgrading k8s infrastructure from 1.8 to 1.14 and seems like I totally confused between options: --admission-controls (which is deprecated), --enable-admission-plugins, --disable-admission-plugins and  plugins which is enabled/disabled by default. Thanks!